# Is it possible to extend structs conforming to a protocol?

Tags: swift, generics

I'm using [SwiftCheck](https://github.com/typelift/SwiftCheck) to do property based testing and I want to generate random elements for several `enum`s conforming to the `CaseIterable` protocol. I thought that instead of writing the same code for all the `enum`s I could do something like the following:

```
extension Any: Arbitrary where Self: CaseIterable {
    public static var arbitrary: Gen<Self> {
        return Gen<Self>.fromElements(of: Self.allCases)
    }
}
```

This fails to compile for several reasons, the main one being

```
Error:(13, 1) non-nominal type 'Any' cannot be extended
```

Is there any way to express this in Swift?

Comment: `Any` is very bad and – as the error states – not an extendable type.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I just was including it to express the intention of what I'm trying to achieve: add protocol conformance and a computed property in a generic way to all the struct types that already conform to another protocol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply extend `CaseIterable` itself if this computed property is supposed to exist on all types conforming to `CaseIterable`.

```
extension Arbitrary where Self: CaseIterable {
    public static var arbitrary: Gen<Self> {
        return Gen<Self>.fromElements(of: Array(Self.allCases))
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, as I need the structs to conform to the Arbitrary protocol, not only to add the computed property. In addition using this code and adding an extension declaring protocol conformance to every involved struct causes another compiler error: generic parameter 'S' could not be inferred

Comment: @JoséGonzález check my updated answer, I've tested it in the SwiftCheck playground and it compiles just fine

Comment: I've marked the answer as accepted, but it feels a bit hacky (not criticising your answer, but Swift itself):
1. I think my code, although incorrect, better expresses the intent: to add conformance to the Arbitrary protocol to anything conforming to CaseIterable. With your code you need to additionally add the Arbitrary conformance in an extension
2. The code wasn't compiling because the compiler wasn't able to properly infer a generic parameter related with Self.allCases: you need to build a new collection. (I've edited your answer to remove the Hashable constraint, using an Array)

Comment: @JoséGonzález You can modify the extension to be on `Arbitrary` and make the conditional conformance require `CaseIterable` conformance too. Check my updated answer.

Comment: The updated code just changes the protocol which is extended, but it still doesn't express the intent of adding Arbitrary conformance to anything conforming to CaseIterable: you still have to declare the struct to both conform to CaseIterable and Arbitrary, either in the declaration of the struct or in an extension. In fact I prefer the previous version, as it better expreses the intention of "add this code to any CaseIterable that conforms to Arbitrary".